# Flat Surface Shader (fss.js) size to 100%?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a responsive site and therefore need to give the canvas a vertical and horizontal width of 100% - but it somehow doesn't work.
I found out that it is possible to change some values for h and w in the script window at

```
var geometry = new FSS.Plane(600, 400, 6, 4);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't take percentages.

1. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99DS3/1/
2. Demo: http://codepen.io/wouwi/pen/Apvaq (Someone else experimented with the svg version of it and somehow got it to 100%)

EDIT: I already tried setting the w and h of the canvas CSS to 100% (even with `!important`) - didn't work.

Comment: updated it to the new source

Comment: Take window h + w on ready? something like that?

Comment: I just posted an answer, I'm deleting my comments to keep this clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you simply erase the canvas and recreate the plane?

**Relevant JS:**

```
function resize() {
    var width = container.offsetWidth, // No need to query these twice, when in an onresize they can be expensive
        height = container.offsetHeight;

    renderer.setSize(width, height);

    scene.remove(mesh); // Remove the mesh and clear the canvas
    renderer.clear();

    geometry = new FSS.Plane(width, height, 6, 4); // Recreate the plane and then mesh
    mesh = new FSS.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh); // Readd the mesh
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/99DS3/3/

Comment: Just perfect! Thanks! I'm a total beginner in JS but im glad that there are people like you guys that come up with solutions like that :)

Comment: I've actually never heard of FSS before, I just looked at what was done in the codepen demo and tried to adapt it.